# Can a VDSL2 to Ethernet converter be used as a replacement for a bridging VDSL2 modem?

Tags: ethernet, adsl, modem

I've got my own network infrastructure already, but I'm tied to my ISPs modem which is a bit on the flaky side. The modem is in bridging mode, with the perimeter router behind it handling authorization via PPPoE.

I want to replace it with something as simple and no-frills as possible.

After happening upon these [VDSL2 to Ethernet converters](https://planetechusa.com/vc-231-100-100-mbps-ethernet-to-vdsl2-converter-30a-profile/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI5MHp4Kyq1QIVCUwNCh1UVwJ6EAQYAyABEgJQgfD_BwE), I want to know if this general class of devices can be used, provided I handle the networking specifics on my router.

Is this possible or advisable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particular device you have listed is required to be used as a pair. This is for someone who want to extend a network across voice cabling, or for a small ISP to use to connect to customers. It doesn't work as a general replacement for a DSL modem.

This is explained in the device description (my emphasis):

> The VC-231 provides CPE and CO mode for application. The CPE mode is
>   used by the client, while the CO mode is used at the central location.
>   These modes can be adjusted with a DIP switch that is built in. **In
>   order to obtain a point-to-point connection, a single CPE mode VC-231
>   converter and another CO mode VC-231 converter must be installed as a
>   pair.**

Normally, an ISP that allows you to use your own DSL device will have a list of compatible devices. There are multiple DSL standards, and you would need to use a device compatible with the standard used by your ISP.